# PHP logical operator base on string

Tags: php

Is there a way to make something like this:

```
$bob = $request->bob;

return $bob in_array()....
```

to resolve to something like

```
return ! in_array()....
```

or

```
return in_array()....
```

base on the variable value...

Comment: I'd like more insight into what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Scuzzy just trying to avoid duplicated code when the only thing that change is the negation symbol

Comment: **Side question**: Do you have known any other language before PHP?

Comment: @SaidbakR why? how is that relevant?

Comment: this is a school project isn't it; where the method is more important than the solution......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `?:`

```
return $variable ? in_array('x', $some_arr) : !in_array('x', $some_arr);
```

Comment: The idea is to avoid repeat values.... ternary conditions are nice but is not a good for this case.

Comment: @jycr753 php is not python - I've never seen what you ask for in the way you ask for it.

Comment: Yeah I think you are right...:(